# Neo4j formulating Cypherquery, performance issue, multiple startpoint

Tags: performance, neo4j, spring-data

I have to execute the following Query:

```
@Query("START whps=node:__types__(className = 'de.adma.domain.WHProcessStep'), 
csd=node:__types__(className = 'de.adma.domain.CSDocument'),
whm=node:__types__(className = 'de.adma.domain.WHMachine')
MATCH whps<-[r1:RELATES_TO]-csd<-[r2:OCCURS_IN]-whm
WHERE (whps.id IN {0}) AND (csd.id IN {1})
RETURN DISTINCT whm ")
```

Each of these classes (CSDocument, WHMachine, ..) have the same scaffold:

```
@NodeEntity
public class CSDocument {
 @GraphId
 Long nodeId;
 @Indexed(unique = true)
 String id;
 @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "accessUri")
 String accessUri;

 // .. definition of some RelatedToVia-Relationships and getter/setters
}
```

Is the query as formulated the correct way to query neo4j?

Currently this works fine for small amounts up to ~100k Nodes/Relationships (query needs <5 seconds).
I need this for ~10mio Nodes/Relationship, but the query runs **several minutes**.

My test environment is a VM, Xeon 2,18Ghz (hexacore), 32GB Ram, SSD.
JVM config:
-Xmx14000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=4048m
-Xss3068m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
I am using Neo4j embedded 1.8.1 inside an Java-Spring application.

Any ideas how i could improve the performance?
Is there an other way for the multiple startpoints when using the IN-statement? It seems as these multiple starting points slows down the queries.

Do I have to define an index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index lookup on your id-index:

```
@Query("START whps=node:WHProcessStep(id = {0}), 
              csd=node:CSDocument(id = {1})
        MATCH whps<-[:RELATES_TO]-csd<-[:OCCURS_IN]-whm
        RETURN DISTINCT whm ")
```

If you want to pass multiple id's to the index you unfortunately have to pass the whole index query as parameters to your method:

```
@Query("START whps=node:WHProcessStep({0}), 
              csd=node:CSDocument({1})
        MATCH whps<-[:RELATES_TO]-csd<-[:OCCURS_IN]-whm
        RETURN DISTINCT whm ")
Collection<WHMachine> find(String whps, String csd);
```

where the two strings are: String whps = "id:(id1 id2 id3)";

Comment: good point, this can be handled by an index lookup because of the id thing.

Answer (score 1):

Is it better if you simply drop these parts of your START clause?

```
csd=node:__types__(className = 'de.adma.domain.CSDocument'),
whm=node:__types__(className = 'de.adma.domain.WHMachine')
```

You're making a cartesian product of all of your start variables and then reducing it in the match. It will be quicker to do type checks after the match.

Comment: I thought I have to do this because of the IN-clause?

Comment: It binds the csd, whm identifiers in the match clause, based on the pattern traversal.

Comment: Better yet, figure out the lowest cardinality between the three classNames, and use it in the start, building your others based on the relationships in the match pattern. Then check types after the match, if you need to (other types are connected via the same reltypes).

Comment: Thanks for your help.
all of them have the same cardinality (data is generated with same volume). Hm, I don't understand how this new query with one start type will look like (I am still new to neo4j). Could you provide additional info?

Comment: Just take out the other start points in the start. That will be a good start. The identifiers will be bound in match, as the pattern is matched. I'm thinking I need to do a blog post about some optimization ideas in cypher.

Comment: Thank you. Let me know, if you blog post is published :-)